# create multi-colored thresholded image from grayscale heatmap in python

Tags: python, opencv, python-imaging-library, threshold, image-thresholding

I have a gray-scale images and want to threshold them in 4 range of values (0.035, 0.7, 0.75), displayed by 4 different colors. I need the result saved as images in UINT8 format. The gray-scale image information is as follows:

```
print(type(grads))
print(grads.shape)
print(grads.min())
print(grads.max())
cv2.imshow('1_grads', grads)
cv2.waitKey()

### OUTPUT
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
(512, 512)
0.0
1.0
```

[image]

I have tried the following:

```
thresh_map = Image.new('RGB', grads.shape, color='white')
thresh_map = np.where(grads < 0.035, (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0))
thresh_map = np.where(0.035 < grads < 0.7, (0, 0, 255), (0, 0, 0))
thresh_map = np.where(0.7 < grads < 0.75, (0, 255, 0), (0, 0, 0))
thresh_map = np.where(0.75 < grads, (0, 255, 0), (0, 0, 0))
```

This returns this Error:
`ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (512,512) (3,) (3,)`

I have somehow solved the problem by using for loops and pasting the pixel values one by one. But it is not nice and takes forever, considering the fact that I am going to apply this to ~4000 images.

```
thresh_map = Image.new('RGB', grads.shape, color='white')
blac = Image.new('RGB', (1, 1), color='black')
blue = Image.new('RGB', (1, 1), color='blue')
redd = Image.new('RGB', (1, 1), color='red')
gree = Image.new('RGB', (1, 1), color='green')
for i in range(grads.shape[0]):
    for j in range(grads.shape[1]):
        print(i, j)
        if grads[i, j] < 0.035:
            thresh_map.paste(blac, (i, j))

        elif .035 < grads[i, j] < 0.7:
            thresh_map.paste(redd, (i, j))

        elif 0.7 < grads[i, j] < 0.75:
            thresh_map.paste(gree, (i, j))

        elif 0.75 < grads[i, j]:
            thresh_map.paste(blue, (i, j))

np_thresh_map = np.asarray(thresh_map)
cv2.imshow('1_thresh', np_thresh_map)
cv2.waitKey()
```

[image]

Is there a more sophisticated and efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my solution using NumPy's [boolean array indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing). The code should be straightforward. If not, please ask. I'll then provide some more explanations.

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Set up some random grayscale image; and sort for better visualization
image = np.sort(np.random.rand(300, 400))

# Given thresholds
thresholds = [0.035, 0.7, 0.75]

# Expand threshold with boundaries
thresholds = np.concatenate(([0], thresholds, [1]))

# Initialize output, and map colors
map = np.zeros((image.shape[0], image.shape[1], 3), np.uint8)
colors = np.array([[255, 0, 0], [128, 128, 0], [0, 0, 255], [0, 255, 0]])

# Iterate ranges; find proper pixel indices; set proper color in map at these indices
for i in range(len(thresholds)-1):
    idx = (thresholds[i] <= image) & (image < thresholds[i+1])
    map[idx, :] = colors[i, :]

# Show image and map
cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.imshow('map', map)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The `image` might look like this:

[image]

And, the corresponding `map` looks like this:

[image: Map]

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can use matplotlib to create a discrete colormap using a BoundaryNorm as normalizer:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

#generate some data
dx, dy = 0.002, 0.002
y, x = np.mgrid[slice(0, 1 + dy, dy),
                slice(0, 1 + dx, dx)]
z = np.sin(x)**1.5 + np.cos(10 + y*x) * np.cos(x)
z = z[:-1, :-1]/z.max()

#define colormap
cmap = matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap(["red", "blue", "green", "black"])
bounds = np.array([0,0.035,0.7,0.75,1])
norm = mpl.colors.BoundaryNorm(bounds, cmap.N)

#Plot
fig, axs = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10),nrows=2,ncols=1,gridspec_kw={'height_ratios': [20,1.5]})
pcm=axs[0].pcolormesh(x,y,z,cmap=cmap,norm=norm)
#colorbar
cbar=fig.colorbar(pcm,cax=axs[1], extend='both', orientation='horizontal')
```

this is the result:
[image]

**Edit**
To save your data you can use [matplotlib savefig function](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.savefig.html). If you don't want to display the colorbar you can remove the last line from the script above. You can also remove the ticks and their labels using:

```
axs[0].get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
axs[0].get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, It is what I need.  But I don't understand which variable holds the result at the end. Which one can I save to file?

Comment: You can use matplotlib savefig function, see my edit to the post.